# how to fix package versions after downgrading python

Tags: python, pip

I recently had to downgrade my python version from 3.8 to 3.6. All of a sudden I'm getting `No module named 'onnx.onnx_cpp2py_export'` errors which (according to a quick google) are the result of some old packages being installed under 3.8 and not properly downgraded to 3.6. How can I fix all these package version errors?

Is there a simple command for me to view which python version each package was installed under? Is there a simple command for pip to try and resolve all versions on its own?

Comment: Do you not have a `requirements.txt` file that actually pinned the versions of the modules you were using? Also, you might run into an issue where the package developer doesn't support lower versions of Python

Comment: I have an `environment.yml` is that similar enough? I'm not terribly familiar with best practices here... Also I have to use python 3.6 because one the packages I need does not support anything higher